# Descobrir versão do LOG4J

Tags: spring-boot

Como eu posso verificar qual versão do LOG4J o meu projeto Spring boot está usando?

Comment: Já procurou no arquivo `pom.xml`?

Comment: Sim, a biblioteca em questão não está citada.

Comment: Vc pode rodar `mvn dependency:tree`, que mostra toda a árvore de dependências.

Comment: opa @hkotsubo, eu escrevi a resposta pra o caso de um projeto que não utiliza gerenciadores de pacotes. Você vai criar uma resposta com sua sugestão?

Comment: @Danizavtz Não. Pode adicionar na sua resposta - eu colocaria "*caso esteja usando Maven*", já que a pergunta não deixa claro (ou poderia editá-la, já que isso foi confirmado nos comentários). E se quiser, pode adicionar mais coisas,  fazendo um compilado [dessas respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37438652)

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema independente de plataforma e IDE, é exibir em tela as informações da lib log4j em seu projeto. Essa mensagem será impressa no console.

Basta fazer o seguinte:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Layout;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Package p = Layout.class.getPackage();
        System.out.println("Implementation title:   " + p.getImplementationTitle());
        System.out.println("Implementation vendor:  " + p.getImplementationVendor());
        System.out.println("Implementation version: " + p.getImplementationVersion());
    }
}
```

A informação que precisa está na chamada do método `getImplementationVersion()`.

Para mais informações consulte a documentação do [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html)

---

Outra possibilidade é verificar a lib que está no **classpath** da aplicação, em geral (dependendo da maneira que importou) a versão do binário vem no nome do jar.

Supondo que está com o projeto aberto na IDE

Navegar para `File`> `Project Structure` > `Libraries`

Veja a imagem para mais detalhes.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Caso esteja usando Maven

Se estiver utilizando maven, pode utilizar o comando:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Isso vai te dar um resultado parecido com a seguinte, vou colocar em destaque apenas onde aparece uma informação da versão do log4j:

```
...
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
...
```

---

Caso nenhum dos resultados acima sejam efetivos, o que pode fazer é "extrair" o conteúdo do .jar da *lib* log4j de seu projeto. Você pode fazer isso pois um arquivo com extensão .jar é um .zip.

Após fazer os passos descritos acima, será possível ver uma estrutura de pastas do ".jar". Vá para o diretório **META-INF** e procure o arquivo `MANIFEST.MF`.

Abra este arquivo, e procure pelo texto `Implementation-Version`. Lá vai conter a informação que deseja.

Segue um exemplo do conteúdo do arquivo MANIFEST.MF:

```
...
Specification-Title: Apache Log4j to JUL Bridge
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Implementation-Title: Apache Log4j to JUL Bridge
Bundle-Description: The Apache Log4j binding between Log4j 2 API and java.util.logging (JUL).
Automatic-Module-Name: org.apache.logging.tojul
Implementation-Version: 2.20.0 #<--INFORMAÇÃO QUE DESEJA
...
```

Repare que no código acima estou destacando apenas a informação da versão do log4j, mas esse arquivo possui outras informações, então tenha certeza de usar a ferramenta adequada para procurar esta informação no arquivo.

Esta resposta utiliza um compilado de soluções existentes nesta thread do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37438652/4598175)